# Using Levenberg-Marquardt method in scipy's least_squares function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to solve a (nonlinear least squares) toy problem by using the [`scipy.optimize.least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) function in Python.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

a = 2
b = -1

def myfun(x,a,b):
    return [a*x[0]-x[1]-np.exp(-x[0]), b*x[0]+2*x[1]-np.exp(-x[1])]

x0 = [-5,-5]
sol = least_squares(myfun,x0,method='lm',ftol=1e-9,xtol=1e-9, \
                    max_nfev=1e6,args=(a,b))

print(sol)

'''
method='trf' solution:  x = array([0.56714329,0.56714329])
'''
```

If I use the Levenberg-Marquardt method `method='lm'` then I get an error `TypeError: integer argument expected, got float`. Am I missing an input argument for `least_squares`? I don't have any further information for the problem, e.g. Jacobian matrix, so I'm not sure if this method particularly suitable for the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write `max_nfev=1000000`, or `max_nfev=int(1e6)` if you prefer exponential notation.

`1e9` is a floating point literal but `max_nfev` should be an integer. Apparently, the LM algorithm checks this, while other algorithms may silently accept a float.

Note the difference between *value* and *data type*:

`1` is an integer with value one, `1.0` is a float with value one. Mathematically, both have the same value but they are not the same thing because they have different data types.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. It looks like `max_nfev=int(1e6)` is necessary for the LM algorithm, but `trf` and `dogbox` will accept either `max_nfev=1e6` or `max_nfev=int(1e6)`.